# netsh command to add interface

Tags: networking, ipv4, netsh

I am working with Windows 2012 R2 Core and I having problems with setting up my NICs after they got reset.

When I run "netsh int show int" it shows bother Interfaces as Enabled and Connected.

When I run "netsh int ipv4 show config" it only shows the "Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1".   I have two NICs on the server "Ethernet 2" and "Ethernet 3".   How to enable them show they have an interface in ipv4?

Everything has to be done in either CMD or Powershell.  There is no GUI.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

> Everything has to be done in either CMD or Powershell. There is no GUI.

You can use Windows Admin Center, a web-based GUI for Windows Server (Core). Sometimes it may be more convenient compared to CMD or Powershell. Windows Admin Center can be installed on the same host that you need to manage on any other Windows machine in your network. Network management is fully implemented, so it may help you with your problem.

[Official overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/manage/windows-admin-center/overview) and step-by-step [installation guide](https://www.starwindsoftware.com/blog/windows-admin-center-for-windows-server) might help.

Answer (score 0):

With Server 2012 R2 you can turn on the GUI to configure what you need. Then remove it afterwards to put it back to core if you really get into a bind.

I ran **netsh int ipv4 show config** on server 2012 R2 with GUI installed and got the proper results (this machine had a static IP).
I also ran it on a Windows 7 machine with DHCP enabled and got the proper results as well.

I'd make sure IPV4 is enabled on each of those interfaces.
As that could be why your are not seeing those interfaces with the command.

Might help:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490943.aspx

Comment: How do I enable IPv4 for each interface through netsh?   I've tried netsh int ipv4 install and it seems to install but how do I enable it for each interface then?

Comment: To show which interfaces have IP4v :
netsh int ipv4 show interfaces enabled
\
Maybe this command to install:
netsh int ipv4 install
Usage: install
Remarks: Installs the IP protocol.
         Restarting computer is required for this action to take effect.
A reboot to the machine is needed.
This would be odd if IPv4 was not enabled though.
\
From server core I was thinking you could also try the **sconfig** command to get to the configuration settings options.

Comment: Sconfig doesn't show any network adapters.   The "show interfaces" only shows loopback interface, even without enabled parameter.   Is there a way to add interfaces?

Answer (score 0):

Some commands I use on Windows 2012 R2 core. Have in mind that if you have Hyper-V installed and assigned a NIC to a virtual switch, it's no longer shown, since it can't be using by the host system.

`Netsh interface ipv4 show interfaces`
`netsh interface ipv4 show subinterfaces` (further info)

`wmic nicconfig get description,ipaddress` (list of NICs using wmic)

`netsh interface ip set interface name=[id] enabled` (to enable NIC or disable it, using `disabled')

Using powershell:
`Get-NetAdapter`